# jQuery - If a selector exists add attribute and prefix value

Tags: jquery

I can't quite figure out the best way to approach this. I've got a conditional that sets a cookie
based on if a selector exists. There are other places in the code where I do something similar if 
the selector exists. If the selector exists I either add "nba" or "nba-" (notice the dash) to various 
attributes on the page. I'm trying to remove as much code as I can as there are about five other places
I have similar places where I'm adding other attributes. I also feel like there's a better way
to approach this without having to write this a ton of times:

```
if($(".userLocation").length > 0){
```

I'm banging my head on how to condense this but can't figure this out. Please include code samples
I learn best that way.

```
    if($(".userLocation").length > 0){
        var user_cookie = {
        name: 'nba-user-profile',
        options: {
            path: '/',
            expires: 365
        }
        };
    } else {
        var user_cookie = {
        name: 'user-profile',
        options: {
            path: '/',
            expires: 365
        }
        };
    }

if($(".userLocation").length > 0){
$('header').attr("href","#nba-city");
$('header').attr("href","#nba-state");
} else {
$('header').attr("href","#city");
$('header').attr("href","#state");
}

if($(".userLocation").length > 0){
$('header').attr("title","#nbacity");
$('header').attr("title","#nbastate");
} else {
$('header').attr("title","#city");
$('header').attr("title","#state");
}
```

Comment: I didn't get the problem. If you want to avoid to repeat the if(condition) create a boolean function, or store the boolean value in a variable in you're using these if in the same function

Comment: why don't you write that condition once & change all the attributes in one block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be not efficient, but you can try something like

```
function existThenDo(selector, successCallBack, failCallback){
    if($(selector).length){
        successCallBack();
    } else {
        failCallback();
    }
}
```

Usage

```
existThenDo(".userLocation", function(){
    $('header').attr("title","#nbacity");
    $('header').attr("title","#nbastate");
}, function(){
    $('header').attr("title","#city");
    $('header').attr("title","#state");
});
```

Comment: Sorry @Satpal a tad confused here, because what if I want to prefix it with nba- instead of nba?

Comment: @DelmonYoung, Why are you confused? As you are performing multiple operation at multiple location. I have just wrapper your if in a function. No you can do whatever you want in __successCallBack__ and __failCallback__

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this. Create a prefix variable. If the selector exists, set it to your prefix value, otherwise keep it blank. Then just append whatever is there:

```
var prefix = '';


if($(".userLocation").length > 0)
    prefix = 'nba-';

var user_cookie = {
    name: prefix + 'user-profile',
    options: {
        path: '/',
        expires: 365
    }
};

$('header').attr("href","#" + prefix + "city");
$('header').attr("href","#" + prefix + "state");
```

This reduces the necessary code by half since you don't have to repeat the same thing in if/else blocks.